# No Ubuntu Control panel in Windows 7 installation

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed 12.04 using the Ubuntu installer for Windows.  I'm able to boot into either OS fine.

I get the impression there's supposed to be some kind of control panel for Ubuntu in the Windows Controller Center.  There is no control panel, or program entry for Ubuntu related applications, in my Windows 7.

Am I missing something?  Searching online didn't turn up much.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect to see a Ubuntu control panel for windows? To my knowledge, none exists.

However, you should see a Ubuntu entry in your add/remove programs list, which appears in wubi (Windows UBuntu Installer) installations. You can use it to delete Ubuntu installation, as if it were another program within windows.

Comment: Ah, thanks Mahesh.  Content I'd read online seemed to suggest there was a control panel.  Perhaps I was confusing a combination of the Add/Remove entry in the Programs panel, plus the Ubuntu One control panel in Ubuntu.  Thank you or clarifying that.